# Using Configuration in C# code

Tags: c#, ini

How to use or operate an ini file using `C#`. Like reading, writing section, keys, values. I heard about nin.dll(or something like that) but I unable to use it. Also i am using sharpdevelop and dot net version 4.0 Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where you able to get some code working partially?

Answer (score 0):

You can just [import the native Windows API calls](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1966/An-INI-file-handling-class-using-C) `GetPrivateProfileString()` and `WritePrivateProfileString()`.